# Supertest and Mongoose Middleware (post remove)

Tags: express, mongoose, mocha.js, chai, supertest

I have been fiddling with this for days, and I cannot figure out why the Mongoose middleware is not being invoked.

So I have an API in node.js and I have a website using Angular.js. The Mongoose middleware is this:

```
schema.post('remove', function (doc) {
    console.log('doctors - post - remove');
});
```

So this hook is called perfectly fine when invoked from the Angular front end. However, when I run a test with **supertest**, **chai**, and **mocha** the hook is not invoked. Here is my code for the testing:

```
it('/doctors - POST - (create doctor)', function(done){
  request(app)
    .post('/doctors')
    .send(doctor)
    .end(function (err, res){
      if (res.body['error']) {
        expect(S(res.body['error']).startsWith('doctor already exists')).to.be.true;
      }
      else
        expect(res.body['email']).to.equal(doctor['email']);
      done();
    });
});

....

it('/doctors/remove - DELETE', function(done){
  request(app)
    .del('/doctors/remove')
    .auth(new_doctor_creds["email"], new_doctor_creds["pass"])
    .end(function (err, res){
      expect(Object.keys(res.body).length).to.not.equal(0);
      done();
    });
});
```

And here is my route for the express app:

```
app.delete('/doctors/remove', authController.isAuthenticated, function (req, res, next) {
    var email = req.user['email'];
    Doctors.findOne({email:email}).remove(function (err, removed) {
        if (err) return next(err);

        return res.status(200).send(removed);
    });
});
```

Again, this Mongoose middleware works perfectly fine when invoked from an API call from the Angular app. However, it does not work when tested with supertest. Any ideas on what to do here?

---

EDIT: I tried to recreate this example with a simplified version that way you can see all of the code. So here is a two file version that is STILL not working. Here is the app.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var Doctors = require('./schema');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/m4', function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('connected');

    app.get('/post', function (req, res, next) {
        console.log('create');
        Doctors.create({email:"hello"}, function (err, inserted) {
            if (err) console.log(err);

            res.end();
        });
    });

    app.get('/delete', function (req, res, next) {
        console.log('removed');
        Doctors.remove({email:"hello"}, function (err, removed) {
            if (err) console.log(err);

            res.end();
        });
    });

    http.createServer(app).listen('6000', function () {
        console.log('now listen on localhost:6000');
    });
});
```

and the schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var schema = mongoose.Schema({
    email: { type: String }
});

schema.pre('save', function (next) {
    console.log('doctors - post - save');
    next();
});

schema.post('remove', function (doc) {
    console.log('doctors - post - remove');
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Doctors', schema);
```

Comment: Does the `/doctors/remove` Express route get called at all during your unit tests? What you're saying is everything works fine during your unit test "except" the post remove hook?

Comment: Yes, it gets called with the `it('/doctors/remove - DELETE', function(done){` line. Everything works, expect the __post remove__ hook. It doesn't even get called

Comment: It doesn't make sense. The only reason I see the post remove would not fire is if the actual remove did not complete successfully. Just out of curiosity `/doctors/remove` removes the currently logged in "doctor"? (I assume `req.user` refers to the currently logged in user.

Comment: that is correct, he's logged on through basic auth. And the remove _actually_ removed it because I have a mongo shell pulled up and I'm checking to make sure it deletes every time

Comment: There's no way for me to actually test your code, because you obviously did not share all of it. So I tested a stripped down version (no authentication, a schema with one field, and hardcoded id to find/remove the document), using express, mongoose, mocha, chai and supertest. As I expected, the post remove fires for me. Sorry I can't be of more help. If I can't thing of a possible cause I will post it later.

Comment: What version of Mongoose are you using?

Comment: I'm using 4.0.1. And your previous comment inspired me to do the same, so please see my update. That is essentially the bare minimum and it still is not working for me. The `pre save` works just fine though

Comment: I have a suggestion.  It's too long to post as a comment, so I'm going to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I suggest. Let's perform the `#remove` on the doc found by `#findOne`. If I remember correctly, remove post hooks only works on `Doc#remove` and not on `Model#remove`.

```
schema.post('remove', function (doc) {
    console.log('doctors - post - remove'); // <-- now runs
});

app.delete('/doctors/remove', authController.isAuthenticated, function (req, res, next) {
    var email = req.user['email'];
    Doctors.findOne({email: email}, function(err, doc) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }

      doc.remove().then(function(removed) {
        return res.status(200).send(removed);
      }, function(err) {
        next(err);
      });

    });
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I completely understand what you're doing here. Putting the hook inside the callback of the original operation, that way it acts as a hook in a sense. That is what I am doing now. I just think it is really sloppy to put all of this  code right here (as opposed to putting it in the schema). It doesn't feel like I'm creating a hook for a database, it feels like a code work around, you know what I mean? I appreciate the answer though, this is what I'll have to do if I never figure out the middleware post

Comment: I understand, but this is simply the way Mongoose works (according to the [Mongoose docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html))

Comment: Well thank you for your help. I'll just keep it this way I guess

Comment: By the way, this does run the `post delete hook`. So, technically it answers your question.

Comment: I just tried it and it worked. So apparently, Mongoose middleware for remove does not work if the remove function call includes a query. Is that an accurate assessment?

Comment: Yes. That is accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose post hooks run AFTER the operation is completed, concurrently with operation callbacks. See the comments below:

```js
Doctors.findOne({email:email}).remove(function (err, removed) {
    // All this code and the post hook are executed at the same time
    if (err) return next(err);

    // Here you send the response so supertest#end() will be triggered
    // It's not guaranteed that post remove was executed completely at this point
    return res.status(200).send(removed);
});
```

Post hooks were made to run processes independent of the server response. When you run tests, the server shuts down right after the tests are completed, and maybe it had no time enough to finish the post hooks. In the other hand, when you call the API from a client, normally you keep the server running, so the post jobs can be completed.

Now, there comes a problem: how can we test post hooks consistently? I got up this question because I was looking for a solution to that. If you already have an answer, please post here.